# How to generate random elements depending on previous elements using Quickcheck?

Tags: testing, clojure, generator, quickcheck

I'm using QuickCheck to do generative testing in Clojure.

However I don't know it well and often I end up doing convoluted things. One thing that I need to do quite often is something like that:

- generate a first prime number from a list of prime-numbers (so far so good)
- generate a second prime number which is smaller than the first one
- generate a third prime number which is smaller than the first one

However I have no idea as to how to do that cleanly using QuickCheck.

Here's an even simpler, silly, example which doesn't work:

```
(prop/for-all [a (gen/choose 1 10)
               b (gen/such-that #(= a %) (gen/choose 1 10))]
                (= a b))
```

It doesn't work because *a* cannot be resolved (`prop/for-all` isn't like a `let` statement).

So how can I generate the three primes, with the condition that the two latter ones are inferior to the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `test.check` we can use `gen/bind` as the bind operator in the generator monad, so we can use this to make generators which depend on other generators.

For example, to generate pairs `[a b]` where we must have `(>= a b)` we can use this generator:

```
(def pair-gen (gen/bind (gen/choose 1 10)
                        (fn [a]
                          (gen/bind (gen/choose 1 a)
                                    (fn [b]
                                      (gen/return [a b]))))))
```

To satisfy ourselves:

```
(c/quick-check 10000
               (prop/for-all [[a b] pair-gen]
                 (>= a b)))
```

`gen/bind` takes a generator `g` and a function `f`. It generates a value from `g`, let's call it `x`. `gen/bind` then returns the value of `(f x)`, which must be a new generator. `gen/return` is a generator which only generates its argument (so above I used it to return the pairs).